# Find the number of days in the current member's month

Tags: mdx

I'd like to be able to find the number of days from the `currentmember` of the hierarchy `[Date - Calendar Month]`.

This is my attempt - my custom Measure `NumDaysInMonth` doesn't work for the current month - see screen-print - as it is just counting the number of days that have passed. I've got a feeling that the function `CLOSINGPERIOD` might help but unsure how to use it:

```
WITH    
MEMBER [Measures].[NumDaysInMonth] AS
    COUNT(
        DESCENDANTS(
            [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].CURRENTMEMBER.PARENT,
            [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Day]
        )
    )
MEMBER [Measures].[LastDay] as
    CLOSINGPERIOD(
        [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Day], 
        [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].CURRENTMEMBER
        )
SELECT 
    NON EMPTY
        TAIL(
        [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Day],
        15)
    ON ROWS,
    NON EMPTY
    {
        [Measures].[NumDaysInMonth],
        [Measures].[LastDay] 
    }
    ON COLUMNS
FROM [ourCube]
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

I created this ugly vba function solution - it must be possible to avoid this?

```
WITH    
MEMBER [Measures].[NumDaysInMonth] AS
    COUNT(
        DESCENDANTS(
            [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].CURRENTMEMBER.PARENT,
            [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Day]
        )
    )
MEMBER [Measures].[LastDay] as
    DATEPART(
        "D",
        DATEADD(
            "M",
            1,
            CDATE(
                CSTR(vba!Month([Date].[Date - Calendar Month].CURRENTMEMBER.name))
                +"-01-"
                +CSTR(vba!Year([Date].[Date - Calendar Month].CURRENTMEMBER.name))
                )
            )-1
        )
SELECT 
    NON EMPTY
        TAIL(
        [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Day],
        15)
    ON ROWS,
    NON EMPTY
    {
        [Measures].[NumDaysInMonth],
        [Measures].[LastDay] 
    }
    ON COLUMNS
FROM [ourCube]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have all days of the month in your cube, then a solution like your VBA calculation would be the way to go. MDX does not have its own date calculation logic built in for any dates not in the cube. It only can use members that are available in the cube already.
Another way would be to load all days of a month - even those in future - into the cube. But this would possibly confuse users. And of course, you could calculate the last day of month at cube loading time in the DSV or table/view that you use to load your time dimension. Then you would add your time dimension table as another measure group containing this measure, which would not use `sum` but e. g. `max` as its aggregation function.

As an aside: Your solution will only work if you are sure the `CurrentMember` is a day, not a month or year. You could improve that using

```
IIF(
[Date].[Date - Calendar Month].CurrentMember.Level IS [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Day],
<your calculation>,
NULL
)
```

or whatever you want to use in case something not a day is the `CurrentMember`.